# Puma Workers and Threads Suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, puma

Can you please suggest Puma Workers and Threads per worker for a real-time app and heavy traffic?

I am using Cloudflare Load-balancers with 8 Dedicated Servers each is 64GB RAM and 16 Core (32 Threads) CPU. Please suggest the max/min number of workers and threads I should start my testing.

Ruby 2.7

Rails 6

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 7):

As always, the answer is, "it depends" (on your application).

Here are some articles on the subject that could help guide your testing:

- https://www.speedshop.co/2017/10/12/appserver.html
- https://www.speedshop.co/2020/05/11/the-ruby-gvl-and-scaling.html
- https://www.speedshop.co/2017/12/04/malloc-doubles-ruby-memory.html

(The articles are written by [Nate](https://github.com/nateberkopec), one of the maintainers of Puma.)